# How to mark tables in SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I try to select values from two tables:

```
    SELECT id, alife, login
    FROM players
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, alife, (
        SELECT players.login
        FROM players
        WHERE players.id = id
        LIMIT 0 , 1
    )
    FROM attempts
    ORDER BY `alife`
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

How can I mark each line with table line? Such as

```
ID     ALIFE     LOGIN     TABLE
1      100       Any_A     players
4      90        Any_B     players
3      80        Any_C     attempts
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 SELECT id, alife, login, 'players' as `TABLE`
    FROM players
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, alife, (
        SELECT players.login
        FROM players
        WHERE players.id = id
        LIMIT 0 , 1
    ), 'attempts' as `TABLE`
    FROM attempts
    ORDER BY `alife`
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: No problem.  Also, it's usually discouraged to use a keyword such as `TABLE` as a column name.  But, your call.

Comment: I understanded it, when got error in SQL request, and renamed it with 'tb'.

Answer (score 0):

This is to note that your query is not correct.  The line:

```
WHERE players.id = id
```

is interpreted as:

```
WHERE players.id = players.id
```

based on SQL scoping rules.

Presumably you want the following:

```
SELECT id, alife, login, 'players' as which
FROM players
UNION ALL
SELECT id, alife, (SELECT players.login
                   FROM players
                   WHERE players.id = attempts.player_id
                   LIMIT 0 , 1
                  ), 'attempts' as which
FROM attempts
ORDER BY `alife`
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Also, because the subquery has no `order by` and it would make sense that the `id` relationship is 1-1, phrasing this as a join would be clearer:

```
SELECT id, alife, login, 'players' as which
FROM players
UNION ALL
SELECT a.id, a.alife, p.login, 'attempts' as which
FROM attempts a left outer join
     players p
     on p.id = a.player_id
ORDER BY `alife`
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

If you are working with a large set of data, there are other modifications that can be made to improve performance.